# How can I use EVP_dss1() function of OpenSSL in C?

Tags: c, openssl

I want to use the EVP_dss1() function from OpenSSL in C. 
I just want to create a hash value of a byte array.
I am aware that dss1 should not be used.

I have already searched for examples but found no meaningful results.

Can someone give me a short example?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests https://linux.die.net/man/3/evp_dss1 etc.

Comment: Do it the same way you use any other message digest algorithm with the EVP high-level interface. The `EVP_MD *` argument (such as for `EVP_Digest` or `EVP_DigestInit` is specified with the return value from `EVP_dss1()`. That said, I'm pretty sure it was dropped from OpenSSL1.1, but I think it is still in 1.0.2 (but no much longer, as that is EOL end of 2019, last I checked).

Comment: okay, what's about digest_len? How can I determine that value?

Comment: The digest size if fixed based on the algorithm chosen.  DSS is the same as SHA, so you can use SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH (20)